# Android email app with attachment doesn't carry attachment with itself

Tags: android, forms, email, email-attachments

Trying to test out a simple app that'll take an image from the gallery and pass it on as an attachment for an email, I've done the following:

Code for accessing gallery via ImageButton using intent

```
ivGalerija.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select content image"), 1);

            }
        });
```

OnActivityResult method overridden

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            if(requestCode == 1){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            String pathToMyAttachedFile = imageUri.getPath().toString();
            File file = new File(root, pathToMyAttachedFile);
            if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
                return;
            }
            uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        }
    }
}
```

onClick method on the submit button to open up the email app

```
bSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSubmit);
        bSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                etMesto = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etMesto);
                etUlica = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUlica);
                etOpis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOpis);

                Intent intent = null, chooser = null;

                es = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMesto);

                intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

                intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
                String[] to = {"aco1992@gmail.com"};
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Prijava kvara");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Elektrodistribucija: " + spElektrodistribucija + "\nMesto neovlascene potrosnje: " +
                        etMesto.getText().toString() + "\nUlica i broj: " + etUlica.getText().toString() + "\nOpis: " + etOpis.getText().toString());
                intent.setType("message/rfc822");

                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send email");
                startActivity(chooser);
            }
        });
    }
```

The whole thing works fine without the attachment, text gets passed to the mail body correctly formatted, but there is no attachment. I've made the Uri field static to make it accessible everywhere, not sure if that's something that's where the problem lies. Anyway, without further ado... this code won't carry the image as an intent into the Email app and send it, instead the whole thing happens as if tho there's nothing selected. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do not construct an uri from an uri.

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

But use the original uri instead:

```
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, data.getData());
```

Comment: But the data field is in the OnActivityResult and isn't accessible up there. How should I access it? Thanks for the response btw

Comment: uri = data.getData();  in this way you use the original uri instead of constructing a new one.

Comment: I've deleted everything except imageUri = data.getData() from my OnResultActivity method, made the field static and accessed it back in my submit method where I put it in the putExtra method and it works like a charm. I can't thank you enough, I've been hopeless for days